# Get user geolocation and center Google heatmap using Angular and agm

Tags: angular, google-maps

I am trying to render a Google heatmap, centered to the current user's location.

I am a bit of a newb. I have my basic methods set up, but I am struggling to call the methods at the right time. I know there are various lifecycle hooks in Angular, but I don't think that is what I am looking for(?).

I basically want to first get the geolocation of the user before the map gets rendered, and then render the map with the location of the user as one of the map's properties.

**Currently the map gets render via my view:**

```
<agm-map (mapReady)="onMapLoad($event)">
  <agm-marker></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

But I would like to do it via the component. So the function call would be; 1st `onGetLocatio()` with a callback to `onShowPosition()`, and then finally `onMapLoad()` must be called. Would this be the correct way (calling order), or is there a better way?

**Here are my controller methods:**

```
onGetLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.onShowPosition);
  } else {
    console.log('Not supported by browser!');
  }
}

onShowPosition = (position: any) => {
  this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
  this.currentLong = position.coords.longitude;

  this.currentLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.currentLat, this.currentLong);
  console.log(this.currentLatLng);
}

onMapLoad(mapInstance: google.maps.Map) {
  this.map = mapInstance;
  this.map.setCenter(this.currentLatLng);

  this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    map: this.map,
    data: this.heatMapData
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance!